# How to send pandas dataframe in table format to mail in python

Tags: python, pandas, smtplib

I am trying to send pandas dataframe via mail. I tried but I'm not able to obtain it. My code is

**code**

```
import pandas as pd 
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pdb

ticket_details=pd.DataFrame(list_values,
columns['incident',"short_description","priority","assignment_group"])


#converting a datframe into html table
df=ticket_details.to_html()
send ="xxx@xxx.com"
reciever="xxx@xxx.com"   
subject="incident details "
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['From'] = send
msg['To'] = reciever 
msg['Subject'] =subject      



html_body = str(df)
messagePlain = 'Look at the incident details'
msg.attach(MIMEText(messagePlain, 'plain'))
msg.attach(MIMEText(html_body, 'html')                           
server = smtplib.SMTP("xxx.com")
server.sendmail(send, reciever, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: What *do* you get?

Comment: i am getting nothing , but if i remove that str(df) and just print "df" then i am getting string df in mail

Comment: What mail clients did you try?

Answer (score 1):

First of all please do not share personal information as mail address in your questions. Then the main problem is that you are converting your `df` to `str` and not to an `html` object.

```py
# declare mixed MIME
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')

# convert df to html
table = df.to_html()
# attach to your mail
msg.attach(MIMEText(table, 'html')
```

Comment: now its giving me html file , i need to show dataframe  in mail body only

Comment: why not just copy and paste?  df.to_clipboard() and then paste into the body of the email

Comment: sry but i didnt get you

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML only contains a table and is not formatted as a full HTML page. But it reads correctly with Thunderbird. Anyway, I would add the minimum before and after the table to make it look like an acceptable HTML page:

```
...
prolog='''<html>
<head><title>Incident details</title></head>
<body>
'''
epilog = '</body></html>'

html_body = prolog + df + epilog
...
```

That is not a very nice HTML but at least, it has a `html` bloc, a header containing a title and a body. With that, it should be readable even on less tolerant mail readers.